# FullCalendar - Default Event Duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to be able to change the default duration of any newly created events.

I'm in dayView and if I simply click (not drag&drop) on the calendar, I get a half hour session.

I'd like to set it to one hour by default.

Maybe with this kind of code:

```
, select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    endDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours() + 1);
}
```

This is effectively setting the good endDate but not visualy updated

[image: half hour selection screenshot]

---

**Edit**

I'm trying to make the behavior similar to Google Calendar: If the user clicks it will select a 1h event, but the user can still select half hours.

Answer (score 3):

Based on one of the examples:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    if (title) {
        end = new Date(start);
        end.setHours(end.getHours() + 1);

        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: allDay
        },
        true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

**Before the question's update:**

Something like this should work:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  calEvent.end = new Date(calEvent.start);
  calEvent.end.setHours(calEvent.start.getHours() + 1);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
},
```

Comment: I made a mistake in saying "eventClick". In fact I was talking about the definition of a new session, not an existing one. So it's more about the "select" event. (I've updated my question)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY what happened?

Comment: I hadn't checked and thought it was ok. This example you put is just creating a new event of 1 hour. I was talking about the default _selection_ duration visually displayed when the user does a simple click on the calendar to create the event.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY hm, then set `slotMinutes: 60` for you calendar and that's it. But hours won't be divided into 2 parts anymore.

Comment: Ok I see. Actually I was trying to do like google calendar. If you do a simple click, it selects 1h but manually you still can select individual halfs of hours.

Answer (score 1):

The [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) `select` [callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) allows you to reset the `end` value to whatever you want. The `start` and `end` parameters to the `select` function are `moment.js` dates. You just need to make sure it's not an all-day event by checking `hasTime()`, then you can use moment to add 30 minutes to the `end` time (to make it an hour long):

```
select: function(start, end) {
    if (end.hasTime()) {
        end.add(30, 'minutes');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's temporary solution I've found:

In your fullcalendar.js file, find function called `slotSelectionMousedown`. Change `dates = ...` line(s) to this:

```
    if (cell == origCell && (t.name == "agendaWeek" || t.name == "agendaDay"))
        dates = [
            d1,
            addMinutes(cloneDate(d1), snapMinutes), // calculate minutes depending on selection slot minutes 
            d2,
            addMinutes(cloneDate(d2), snapMinutes + 30)
        ].sort(cmp);
    else
        dates = [
            d1,
            addMinutes(cloneDate(d1), snapMinutes), // calculate minutes depending on selection slot minutes 
            d2,
            addMinutes(cloneDate(d2), snapMinutes)
        ].sort(cmp);
```

Note that this is only temporary solution/hack, as it will be overridden with new Fullcalendar version. You might try to add those lines again, but there's possibility it won't work.